# Drupal 7 passing function as parameter triggers warning

Tags: php, drupal-7

I have developed an identity function in php

```
function identity($id){
  return $id;
}
```

in another function I need to pass this identity function as parameter so I did

```
function poor_man_map($array, $map_fun){
   $return_val = array();
   foreach($array as $key=>$value){
      $return_val[$key] = $map_fun($value);
   }
   return $return_val;
}

function foo(){
  $ids = ['1','2','3'];
  return poor_man_map($ids, identity); //Warning generated

}
```

And I was getting warning as when running simpletest:

**Use of undefined constant identity - assumed 'identity'**

Changing function foo into

```
function foo(){
          $ids = ['1','2','3'];
          return poor_man_map(
                   $ids, 
                   function($id){ 
                     return identity($id);
                   });         
  }
```

did get rid of the warning but it made the code much more cumbersome.

This is my first drupal/php project. So, I may be missing something very obvious. Can you tell me what I did wrong?

My environment is: 
  Drupal 7,
  Php 5.4.24
  Windows 7

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass the argument as a string:

```
return poor_man_map($ids, 'identity');
```

By the way, this is not related to drupal, just php. See a [working example](http://codepad.viper-7.com/biw3iy).

Comment: Thanks. that helps a lot. Can you tell me why passing a string makes the interpreter happy but just the name of function does not?